# How do i render my own html code after creating a react app

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app using the create-react-app app-name on vs code and I'm trying to display my own code in the browser. I've noticed that the `index.js` file renders the `App.js` code, I imported my own class which is the test class from the homepage in the `index.js` file here.
My test class is in a js file called homepage which is inside a file called components

```
import test from './components/homepage';
```

Then I try replacing the App / with my own class in the `reactDOM.render` function here

original

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After modification

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <test />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

when I refresh the development server (the tab which react opens I write npm start) none of my html code in the test class displays. I'm relatively new in react so sorry if this seems kind of basic

Full code in the test class

```
import  React from 'react';
class test extends React.Component()
{
  constructor(props)
  {
      super(props);
      const current = new Date();
      this.state={
      //date: `{current.getDate()}/${current.getMonth()+1}/${current.getFullYear()}`
      };
  }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Tempthelete</h1>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <div id="d1">
                    <h2>London</h2>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>image</td>
                            <td>Temprature</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>weather descriptiom</td>
                            <td>High and low tempratures</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br></br>
                    </div>

            </div>
        );
    };
}
export default test;
```

Full index.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import test from './components/homepage';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <test />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: A react component should start with a capital letter. Replace everywhere in your code `test` with `Test`.

Comment: It should be `extends React.Component` instead of `extends React.Component()`, note the removal of the round brackets.

Comment: @Ameer is right. And I would tell you that nowadays you should be learning functional component oriented React.

Comment: @yousoumar I changed 'test' to 'Test' and now it recognizes that im using a react component.  But my HTML code in the test class is still not displaying any ideas why ?

Comment: Okay did you do what @Ameer said ?

Comment: @yousoumar oh nevermind, I forgot to remove the brackets after components like ameer said its working fine now. Thank you all for the help

Comment: Glad it worked out.